# Use one small sound file to compose a song

Tags: python, audio

Suppose I have a song, and I want to reproduce the same song using repetitive versions of a smaller sound file (let's call it 'x'). Now, to reproduce the same song, 'x' would need to have same frequencies at different samples of the original song.

To achieve this, I am determining the frequencies of the main song at it's original rate, then I would have to change the frequency of 'x'. How can I do that? Am I going in the right direction?